# mysql-workbench cannot open, symbol lookup error?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, and I cannot start mysql-workbench downloaded from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/).

When I tried to start workbench it shows:

```
➜ mysql-workbench
Found /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.12
/usr/bin/mysql-workbench-bin: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libwbprivate.so.8.0.18: undefined symbol: _ZN7pcrecpp2RE4InitEPKcPKNS_10RE_OptionsE


➜ mysql-workbench --version
Found /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproj.so.12
MySQL Workbench CE (GPL) 8.0.18 CE build 15329599


➜ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Comment: Please add output of `ldd /usr/lib/mysql-workbench/libwbprivate.so.8.0.18` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1201645/edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out one solution. I just uninstall 8.0.18 version, and use the version 6.3.8 from the apt source.

```
sudo apt purge mysql-workbench
sudo dpkg -r mysql-workbench-community
```

and reinstall mysql-workbench

```
sudo apt install mysql-workbench
```

Comment: Did you check if the service is active? running  $ systemctl is-enabled mysql

Answer (score 0):

I think there is compatibility issue. Remove the previous one and try to install it with the apt command.

`sudo apt update
 sudo apt install mysql-workbench`

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I've tried this way. not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled mysqlworkbench

```
sudo apt remove mysql-workbench
```

then i downloaded package from official website[hear](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/). After that i installed with bellow command

```
dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community_8.0.19-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb
```

after that i run

```
mysql-workbench
```

although it is contrary to what other people suggest that install using apt or apt-get but that not worked and this thing worked for me